# Is there a metric in which 1+2+3+4+... converges to -1/12?

Tags: metric-spaces, summation, riemann-zeta, divergent-series, regularization

It is well known that the sum $1+2+3+4+\ldots$, which tends to infinity in the regular sense, can be assigned the value $-\frac{1}{12}$ by different means, e.g., zeta regularization or different summation methods.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780152/is-there-a-base-in-which-1-2-3-4-dots-frac112-makes-sense) asked if there was a base in which the sum would make sense, though no positive answer was given.

What I was wondering: The notion of convergence depends on the metric we use. Particularly, we would conventionally say that the series must diverge since the terms do not get closer to $0$. But is there a metric where the sequence $1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots$ tends to $0$ such that the series $1+2+3+4+\ldots$ converges, and the limit would indeed be $-\frac{1}{12}$, or possibly some other value? I would think p-adic numbers are a pretty good candidate, but I have very limited knowledge in the field.

Comment: Well, your thought about p-adic numbers is good. You should  read something about it. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does $1+2+3+\dots = -\frac{1}{12}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-dots-frac112)

Comment: @Integrator This isn't a duplicate he is asking for an arbitrary metric under which this sum converges. The other question is asking why a given function has a particular value.

Comment: In (odd-)$p$-adics, triangular numbers tend to be [attracted to $-1/8$](https://mathoverflow.net/a/441585/86625) instead of $-1/12$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example (though it's a bit silly). Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be some bijection such that $f(n) = \frac{1}{n}$ and $f(\frac{-1}{12}) = 0$, and define a metric on $\mathbb{R}$ by $d(x,y) = |f(x) - f(y)|$. You can easily check that this satisfies all the axioms of a metric. And $d(1+2+\cdots+n, -1/12) = 1/(1+2+\cdots+n) \to 0$, so for this metric the series $\sum_k k$ converges to $-1/12$.

But as you can see the metric doesn't have a lot to do with the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$, or with the usual addition/multiplication.

Comment: Thanks for that! I guess $f(x)$ really only needs to be an injection (not necessarily a bijection), and only for $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$, right? Anyway, this would work for any sequence and any value as the limit. Is there any more natural metric that's specific to this and would offer some insight?

Comment: Is there a non-trivial example, like how $1+2+4+8+\dots$ converges to $-1$ in the 2-adics? I'm tempted to open a new question.

Comment: Moreover, how can $f$ be a surjection? What's the pre-image of $-12$?